# Record SRV or A-Record Traffic

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel, srv

I am looking for a way to monitor and record traffic hits to an SRV or A-Record on my Linux Box running cPanel. The records would point to an external application with no built in logging abilities. Is it possible to somehow "spy" on the traffic that hits those records, and see how many hits they get and where they are from?

Comment: You can have BIND (assuming you are using that for DNS) record all queries arriving and being handled into a log file. Then process the log file. This of course will lack `cached` DNS incoming requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @nrathaus suggestion, I will just enable logging for BIND, and then I can process the log programmatically!